# Unset an array element inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, reference, foreach, unset

I'm accessing an array by reference inside a foreach loop, but the unset() function doesn't seem to be working:

```
foreach ( $this->result['list'] as &$row ) {
    if ($this_row_is_boring) {
        unset($row);
    }
}

print_r($this->result['list']); // Includes rows I thought I unset
```

Ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're unsetting the reference (breaking the reference).  You'd need to unset based on a key:

```
foreach ($this->result['list'] as $key => &$row) {
    if ($this_row_is_boring) {
        unset($this->result['list'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of note is that array indexes are preserved, even if you did not specify them (automatic numeric indexes) when the array was initialized. That is to say, it will not re-organize numeric array keys to be sequential.

Answer (score 8):

```
foreach ($this->result['list'] as $key => &$row) {
    if ($this_row_is_boring) {
        unset($this->result['list'][$key]);
    }
}
unset($row);
```

Remember: if you are using a  `foreach` with a reference, you should use unset to dereference so that `foreach` doesn't copy the next one on top of it. [More info](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Ummm, if you're using a foreach with a reference, you don't need to unset it on each loop.  PHP does that for you automatically.  You should dereference it **after** the loop.

Comment: That's true... it was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

A bit of an explanation to the answers above.

After `unset($row)` the variable `$row` is unset. That does not mean the data in `$row` is removed; the list also has an element pointing to `$row`.

It helps to think of variables as labels. A piece of data can have one or more labels, and `unset` removes that label but does not touch the actual data. If all labels are removed the data is automatically deleted.