# Unsetting properties in an object

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I am trying to unset something in an object.

```
foreach($curdel as $key => $value) {
if ($value == $deletedinfo[0]) {
    print_r($key);
    print_r($curdel);
    unset($curdel[$key]);
}
}
```

As expected, `$key` returns the correct value (0) and `$curdel` returns the entire array. But trying to unset `$curdel[$key]` breaks everything. even trying to `print_r($curdel[$key])` breaks everything, what am I missing?

My object looks like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [0] => IFSO14-03-21-14.csv [2] => EB_Bunny.jpg [3] => EB_White_Bear.jpg )
```

Comment: What do you mean - breaks everything? Any real error messages?

Comment: Breaks everything? what is the error?

Comment: No errors, nothing renders after I try it.

Comment: print_r $curdel returns:
`stdClass Object ( [0] => IFSO14-03-21-14.csv [2] => EB_Bunny.jpg [3] => EB_White_Bear.jpg )`

Comment: So you know for future questions, this data structure is an object with numeric properties, not an "object array". I suspect that if you use that phrase, people will assume you mean a class that implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
unset($curdel[$key]);
```

Try:

```
unset($curdel->$key);
```

Arrays are accessed/modified via the [] but objects and class properties are accessed via the ->

Comment: This guy, this guy knows whats up.

Comment: Note: `unset($obj->prop)` DELETEs `prop` from the object, such that `__get()` and `__set()` will be invoked on future `$obj->prop` access, even if the property is declared as public.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution to that problem is to add reference to `$value` variable:

```
foreach($curdel as $key => &$value) { //Note & sign
   if ($value == $deletedinfo[0]) {
       print_r($key);
       print_r($curdel);
       unset($curdel[$key]);
   }
}
```

`&$value` means a reference to an actual array element

Answer based also on this (similar) example: [Unset an array element inside a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054886/unset-an-array-element-inside-a-foreach-loop)

***UPDATE***

Based in your input (STDClass instead of array): just cast `$curdel` to array first:

```
$curdel = (array) $curdel ;
```

Numeric indices in objects are kinda invalid and can be accessed only via special syntax like:

```
$object->{'0'} ;
```

which is a really bad practice.

Comment: The foreach and if didn't seem to be the issues as the two print_r are going off.

Comment: Seriously, just explain what input you have and what final result you need to get. Post more code that could possibly cause the problem and we will help you. `Breaks everything` is the same as `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: I think this is a good answer based on the information available at the time: `object != object array`!